# help with web.config file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

im trying to put my website onto a server and im getting the following error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Source Error:

Line 6:  
Line 7:    
Line 8:      
Line 9:    
Line 10:

can some one help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please verify in IIS that your website is indeed running ASP.NET v. 4.0.
In IIS >  Right click on WebSite > Properties > ASP.NET > Version > "Should read 4.0.21006" not 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the AppPool: is it set to .NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the framework associated with your project matches the framework specified in the App Pool settings. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx) for instructions for both IIS6 and IIS7.